# checkbox foreign key belongs to many in Yii

Tags: checkbox, yii, foreign-keys, one-to-many, belongs-to

I'm new to yii framework so i could use some help with something. Lets say i got a table in my database with POST, 1 of the fields is TYPE. In another table i got a lot of types like this:

Table Type:

```
id  name
1   Politic
2   Sport
3   Espiritual
```

Table Post:

```
id  title
1   Politic in Barsovia
2   God exist!
3   Del Po Win in Rotterdam
```

Table Post_type

```
id  id_post id_type
1   1       1
2   2       3 
3   3       2
```

i have relationships in TYPE

```
'posttype' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Post_type', 'ID_TYPE'),
```

i have relationships in POST

```
'posttype' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Post_type', 'ID_POST'),
```

i wan this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/SpringMVC-CheckBox-Example-2.jpg)

QUESTION:

**how to make a list of checkboxes from the table TYPE**

**how to use activeCheckBoxList width CAdvancedArBehavior**

Comment: Please take some time to better express what the problem is and what exactly you are having trouble with (you are expected to make a minimum of effort, including reading any relevant documentation beforehand). As it stands right now, this question is unclear and a prime candidate for closing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CHtml::checkBoxList() (or CHtml::activeCheckBoxList() or its wrapper in CActiveForm). For example, in your controller, you can have this line to retrieve all your related types:

```
$types = CHtml::listData($model->posttype, 'id', 'name'); // prepare the data for check box list
// the rest of your controller code ...
$this->render('create', array(
    'model' => $model,
    'types' => $types,
));
```

In your view, you can use CActiveForm::checkBoxList() to generate the check boxes:

```
<?php echo $form->checkBoxList($model, 'type', $types); ?>
```

Also, I recommend you make your relationships more user-friendly by changing the names: You should have "posts" as the name of your relation in your Type model, and "types" as the name of your relation in the Post model.